# Best solution for managing email-related application on a LAMP stack

Tags: php, mta

We are working on a web application written in PHP where the following needs to happen:

1) Users at signup are given a unique email address by the web application.

2) Users can give out the email address to collaborators who submit content via email

3) A PHP script will have to monitor for new emails

4) New emails will be parsed and loaded into a database for use by the web application.

Right now, I'm looking at using Postfix with Courier on an Ubuntu server and then issuing calls to the system via PHP's exec() or system() commands.

Are there better solutions out there for this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like node.js that can handle the email monitoring and system calls.

Take a look at [node-imap](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap) as a good example.

Comment: The real core of the problem is being able to create / delete mail accounts from the mail server. Whether using node or php, I can easily grab the emails.